# Non linear differential equation solve for time t

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Hi I have following problem, i have a flow vector field given by:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}y^3 - 4x \\ y^3 - y - 3x \end{pmatrix}
$$

and I have to answer the question: Show that $|x(t) - y(t)| \rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$.

My initial idea is to try to solve the DGL but to be frank I have no idea how.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $y^3$ instead of $y3$?

Comment: Subtract one equation from other to get simple equation in $x-y$

Comment: yes sorry made a mistake :) i am already really tired sorry but i dont really understand what you mean with substract?  how should this work with the dx/dt and dy/dt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x'=y^{3}-4x$$
$$y'=y^{3}-y-3x$$
Subtract the second from the first
$$(x-y)'=-(x-y)$$
Thus
$$(x-y)=Ce^{-t}$$
Thus
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}|x-y|=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}|C|e^{-t}={0}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean $y^3$ instead of $y3$, you can simply observe that

$$\dot x - \dot y = y-x \implies \frac{d}{dt}(x-y)=-(x-y) \implies x-y=e^{-t}$$

and the result follows

Answer (score 0):

Note that with $$ u= x-y$$ you get $$\dot u = -u $$

Thus  $$u=u_0 e^{-t} \to 0 \text { as } t\to \infty$$

$$u\to 0 \implies |u|= |x-y|\to 0 $$